# MySQL TIMESTAMP Column - Group by Day

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling with grouping a MySQL TIMESTAMP column by day without any specific where clause.

The goal is to output a list of individual days within the database, currently I get an error regarding non-aggregated columns.

> SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column `created_at` which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by.

My query is:

```
SELECT created_at FROM audits GROUP BY DATE('created_at');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `date()` in both the `select` and `group by`.  Or just use `select distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(created_at)
FROM audits;
```

I should note that your query has two errors.  The expression `DATE('created_at')` is taking the `DATE()` value of a string.  In this context, `date()` returns `NULL`, which isn't useful.

Even if you drop the single quotes (which may be an artifact of the posting), you will still get the error that you state.  The `SELECT DISTINCT DATE(created_at)` or `SELECT DATE(created_at)`/`GROUP BY` will fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your current query there is no group by necessary because you are not using a sum or a count function. I think that you currently have datetimes stored in the created_at field. What you want is to cast that to the date format which goes something like 'CAST(created_at AS date). This gives you the days without the time. Full query:

`Select CAST(created_at AS Date) AS New_Date FROM audits`

Answer (score 0):

you can try below queries:

`SELECT created_at FROM audits GROUP BY date_format('created_at','%d');`

`SELECT date_format('created_at','%d')as created_at_month,count(*) FROM audits GROUP BY date_format('created_at','%d');`

`similarly use
// for year : '%Y'
// for month : '%m'
// for hour : '%H'`